# loop over a dictionary where the value of the key is again a list in ansible

Tags: ansible

The dict is as below-

```
    {
      "user1": ['abc'],
       "user2": ['mono','lolo']
}
```

I would like to iterate over this dict and its values in ansible. Kindly suggest
I have tried with_items and with_nested but is not iterating in the correct sequence(when the key is user1, the value should be abc, but i get mono or sometimes lolo randomly)

Answer (score 0):

Given the dictionary

```yaml
    d1:
      user1: ['abc']
      user2: ['mono','lolo']
```

Use [*dict2items*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) to convert the dictionary to the list and iterate [*with_subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ d1|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'user1'}, 'abc']) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
  - key: user1
  - abc

ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'user2'}, 'mono']) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
  - key: user2
  - mono

ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'user2'}, 'lolo']) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
  - key: user2
  - lolo
```